# Pandas: union two datasets on multiple column key with condition for matched rows

Tags: pandas

I have a situation where I am trying to get a latest current view of data. I have incoming new data in a Pandas dataframe that I need to merge with another dataframe of the existing data.  I have a list that contains the key columns (to match the rows between the 2 dataframes).

I need a resulting dataframe that contains all rows from each dataframe that doesn't exist in the other (based on the key). But also, when the key is in both dataframes, I need to compare the "trantime" column to see which is most recent and use that row.

Here is the setup:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Use this list of columns to join the 2 dataframes.
key_columns = ['col1','col2']

time = datetime.now()

existing_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    col1=[0,1,1,2],
    col2=['a','b','c','b'],
    attr1=['this','is','just','something'],
    trantime=[
        time - timedelta(days=1),
        time,
        time - timedelta(days=2),
        time - timedelta(days=3)
    ]
))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    col1=[1,2,2],
    col2=['b','b','c'],
    attr1=['plus','more','stuff'],
    trantime=[
        time - timedelta(days=1),
        time,
        time]
))

# How do I get this:
expected_output_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    col1=[0,1,1,2,2],
    col2=['a','b','c','b','c'],
    attr1=['this','is','just','more','stuff'],
    trantime=[
        time - timedelta(days=1),
        time,
        time - timedelta(days=2),
        time,
        time
    ]
))
```

I've tried to use isin(), but I haven't been able to get it to work with multiple columns for the key. I assume that I'll be using concat() also. I have tried to use merge(), but this creates columns in the resulting dataframe with a "_x"/"_y" suffix.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

[pandas merge ordered](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_ordered.html) may help, although i guess merge could do the same thing as well :

```
 existing_df = existing_df.sort_values('trantime')
 new_df = new_df.sort_values('trantime')

res = (pd.merge_ordered(existing_df, new_df, on = key_columns)
       #check if there is a new column
       .assign(attr1_x = lambda x: np.where(x.attr1_x.isna() & (x.attr1_y.notna()),
                                            x.attr1_y,x.attr1_x),
               #compare time entries to get latest
           trantime_x = lambda x: np.where((x.trantime_x.isna()|x.trantime_x.lt(x.trantime_y)),
                                           x.trantime_y, x.trantime_x
                                          )
          )
       #strip off the last two columns
       .iloc[:,:-2]
      )

res



   col1 col2    attr1_x        trantime_x
0   0   a       this        2020-06-03 06:59:56.012913
1   1   b       is          2020-06-04 06:59:56.012913
2   1   c       just        2020-06-02 06:59:56.012913
3   2   b       something   2020-06-04 06:59:56.012913
4   2   c       stuff       2020-06-04 06:59:56.012913
```